# How to generate Makefile rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to do generate rules in Makefile by this:

```
# $(call cc-defs, ccfiles)
define cc-defs
    $1.files = $(patsubst %.cc,%.proto,$1)
    $1: $1.files
endef
$(foreach ccfile,$(ccfiles), $(eval $(call cc-defs, $(ccfile))))
```

but failed with error message:

```
Makefile:19: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

Instead that, I can do this by:

```
# $(call cc-defs, ccfiles)
define cc-defs
    $1.files = $(patsubst %.cc,%.proto,$1)
endef

$(foreach ccfile,$(ccfiles), $(eval $(call cc-defs, $(ccfile))))
$(foreach ccfile,$(ccfiles), $(eval $(ccfile):$($(ccfile).files)))
```

How to make the 1st method works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of make are you using? `$(eval)` only appeared in 3.80 (and it only properly works in 3.81 IMHO).

To debug makefiles you'll often have to revert to *printf debugging*. To see what's going on, replace `eval` with `warning`. This shows what you are giving to make:

```
$ make --warn
Makefile:6: warning: undefined variable `ccfiles'
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

(Aside: `--warn-undefined-variables` is always useful. Undefined variables are untidy.)

O.K., so we need to define `$ccfiles`. Now we get the for loop firing:

```
$ make --warn ccfiles=1.cc
Makefile:6:    1.c.files = 1.cc
               1.cc:  1.c.files
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Fine. You have given make no recipes, nor a default target. You also have missed out on some variable expansion, and have an extra space in the `$(for)` invocation (naughty!). Try this:

```
$ cat Makefile
# $(call cc-defs,ccfiles)
define cc-defs
  $1.files = $(patsubst %.cc,%.proto,$1)
  $1: $$($1.files) ; echo '[$$@]'
endef
$(foreach ccfile,$(ccfiles), $(eval $(call cc-defs,$(ccfile))))

$ make ccfiles=1.cc
make: *** No rule to make target `1.proto', needed by `1.cc'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if all you want to do is for all files in a variable to depend on (or be made from) .proto files, you don't need $(eval).

A pattern rule will do (and will work in older versions of GNU Make too):

```
$(ccfiles): %.cc: %.proto
        echo '[$@]'
```

This does have the side effect of complaining when the ccfiles variable contains any entries not named *.cc (although it still executes the rule in that case).

```
$ make ccfiles=hello.cc
make: *** No rule to make target `hello.proto', needed by `hello.cc'.  Stop.
$ touch hello.proto
$ make ccfiles=hello.cc
[hello.cc]
$ make ccfiles=hello.c
Makefile:1: target `hello.c' doesn't match the target pattern
[hello.c]
```

If the variable can contain many things but you only want to add this processing to .cc files, simply add a filter:

```
$(filter %.cc,$(ccfiles)): %.cc: %.proto
        echo '[$@]'
```

This then results in:

```
$ make ccfiles=hello.cc
[hello.cc]
$ make ccfiles=hello.c
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```